# Visually where is the Deadlock? Why? How to avoid/fix?

Tags: operating-system, mutex, semaphore

I am trying to understand and solve the following problem.

> The following program attempts to use a pair of *[semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming))* **t** and **s** for *[mutual exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)*.
>
> **Initially:** *s = 1*, *t = 0*.

```
    Thread 1    Thread 2
    --------    --------
1.  P(s);       P(s);
2.  V(s);       V(s);
3.  P(t);       P(t);
4.  V(t);       V(t);
```

*Please remember that:*

> The **P** operation wastes time or sleeps until a resource protected by
> the semaphore becomes available, at which time the resource is
> immediately claimed.
>
> The **V** operation is the inverse: it makes a resource available again
> after the process has finished using it.

---

> **1. Why does this program cause a deadlock?**
>
> **2. What changes can be made to initial semaphore values to remove deadlock potential?**

---

### UPDATE

According to comments I am able to better understand and illustrate the deadlock visually below, so please let me know if I understood correctly.

> Here is how the deadlock happens, IF Thread 1 gets [CPU Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time) before Thread 2:

[image]

> How to fix this?

Set value of **t** to initially be **1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deadlock is at `Line 3`. At this line both the `Threads` are waiting continuously to acquire lock on resource `t`. The initial value of `t` is 0, which means it is already in a locked state, so for example if `Thread1` reaches first to `line 3` it waits till the value of `t` becomes 1 and similarly after some time `Thread2` will wait at the same line for `t` to become 1. In this way both the process will wait continuously for the resource creating a `deadlock.

Comment: So to fix this potential deadlock it is best to set t=1, initially?

Comment: @lucidgold See the initial value of `t` should be put based on your requirement. It can be any value between `0-n`. For instance, as asked in your question the initial value of `t` is 0, this means that the resource is already locked, to avoid a deadlock in this, you have to call `V(t)` at `line 3` instead of `P(t)`, either in `Thread1` or `Thread2` (Again this depends on your requirement.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. But I just want to make sure that setting t=1 initially would FIX the deadlock on line 3, which would allow Thread 1 to acquire t, which will force Thread 2 to wait,  but eventually no other deadlock should occur assuming only Thread 1 and Thread 2 are accessing t....is this correct?

Comment: @lucidgold That is not true always. Consider this, for example if `Thread 1` and `Thread 2` completed their processing till `line 2`  and after this if `Thread2` again gets the `CPU Time` than the execution will be otherway i.e, `Thread1` will be waiting and `Thread2` acquires lock . else If `Thread1` got the `CPU Time` before `Thread2` the execution would have been as expected by you. So, remember one thing, in this case which thread gets lock on `t`  depends on CPU Scheduling.

Comment: That's is correct! But what I meant to say was that no matter who got CPU time first, when t=1 initially that will NOT allow for a deadlock on line 3 (assuming no other thread/process has access to t)?

Comment: @lucidgold No, it will not occur in above lines of code.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for this, I have up-voted and accepted your answer!

Comment: @lucidgold Thank you. Hoping that you got your doubts cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can avoid deadlocks by lock ordering. For example, all code must lock `s` before it locks `t`. The question demonstrates what can happen if that is not the case. You can "make changes to the initial semaphore values" to conform with lock ordering.

Comment: Why must it lock s before t? I believe @prince is correct...Do you?